# Find $(a,b,c)$ such that $abc = a+b+c+7$ over positive integers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

**Question:**

Find all permutations of $(a,b,c)$ such that $abc = a+b+c+7$ over positive integers.

**Attempt:**

Solving for $c = \frac{a+b+7}{ab -1} \implies (ab-1)|(a+b+7)$

i.e. $ab-1 \le a+b+7 \implies ab-a-b + 1 \le 8 + 1 \implies (a-1)(b-1) \le 9$

From here I took 2 cases:

Case 1:
$(a-1)(b-1) = 9 \implies (a,b,c) = \{ (1,4,4), (1,2,10)\}$ and their permutations (by symmetry).

I don't know how to argue for Case 2: $(a-1)(b-1) < 9$ efficiently.

I could do $(a-1)(b-1) = 1, 2, 3,...8 $ but what's the better way?

Comment: Both $abc$ and $a+b+c$ are invariant under any permutation of the three numbers, so there is nothing to do!!!!? Or are you looking for *solutions*? Or *solutions up to permutations*?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The question was given the exact words they presented to me. I think my prof. is looking for all solutions basically.

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4617178/472818

Comment: @mr_e_man That thread has no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $(a-1)(b-1)\le9$ implies you can wlogcassume $a-1\le3$, thus $a\in\{1,2,3,4\}$. So try each of these four, not eight, cases in turn and see how many symmetrically equivalent solutions emerge.

For instance, drop in $a=1$. Then

$bc=1+b+c+7$

$bc-b-c+1=1+7+1$

$(b-1)(c-1)=9.$

Therefore with $a=1$, $b-1$ and $c-1$ must be divisors of $9$, and you recover the solutions you already identified.

With $a=2$ you have

$2bc=2+b+c+7$

$4bc=4+2b+2b+14$

$4bc-2b-2c+1=4+14+1$

$(2b-1)(2c-1)=19.$

So $2b-1$ and $2c-1$ must divide $19$, and you get only $(2,1,10)$ and $(2,10,1)$ again repeating a previous solution.

I leave $a=3$ and $a=4$ to you, can you identify more symmeyrically nonequivalent solutions?

> There are no more.

Comment: I think you meant to say $\{1,2,3,4\}$ on line 1, and not $\{1,2,34\}$

Comment: Mistyped, thanks.